# Exibr um echo a cada numero X do indice no Foreach Php

Tags: php

Estou tentando acha uma lógica para o meu problema tenho o seguinte foreach

```
 foreach ($Read->getResult() as $LastPDT):
    echo "a";
 endforeach;
```

nesse exemplo se tiver 30 registro ele vai imprimir na tela 30 vezes a palavra "a" certo.
o que eu quero é que a cada 5 registro no foreach ele de mais um echo exemplo

```html
a
a
a
a
conteudo
a
a
a
a
conteudo
a
a
a
a
conteudo
```

eu fiz dessa forma

```html
$contador = 0
foreach ($Read->getResult() as $LastPDT):
  $contador ++;
   if($contador == 5):
     echo "conteudo";
    endif;
echo "a";
endforeach;
```

ao executar retorna o seguinte resultado

```html
 a 
 a 
 a 
 a 
 conteudo
 a 
 a 
 a 
 a 
 a 
 a 
 a
 a
 a 
 a
```

ele mostra o echo somente no primeiro e não continua a mostra a cada 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou somente você zerar seu contador dentro do seu `IF`.

```
$contador = 0
foreach ($Read->getResult() as $LastPDT):
  $contador ++;
   if($contador == 5):
     echo "conteudo";
     $contador = 0; // Zerando contador aqui
    endif;
echo "a";
endforeach;
```

Comment: Nossa obrigado não tinha pensado nisso